# $A$ - dga over field, then $H^i(A) = 0, i > 1$ implies $HH_i(A) = 0, i < -1$

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, differential-graded-algebras

Let $(A,d)$ - dg-algebra with unit over field $k$ such that $H^i(A) = 0$ for $i > 1$, then $HH_i(A) = 0, i < -1$. I prove that using bar resolution, fact that cohomology commutes with filtered colimits and bicomplex spectral sequence. But I am new in homological algebra and not really sure that my proof is valid. So, that can be valid?

It maybe useful to notice that fact $H^i(A) = 0$ for $i > 0$ then $HH_i(A) = 0, i < 0$ is 100% true, it is classical result. So, "my" fact is slightly stronger version of it.

Comment: If you're using the usual definitions then I don't believe the classical result you cite; it should be false already for $A$ the polynomial algebra in two variables concentrated in degree $0$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I messed up some gradings, fixed. It is classsical but I can't find any good reference. If cohomology are negative then we can just delete positive components and will obtain qiso algebra. But negative components will be deleted in Hohscild complex too.

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Did you try a spectral sequence similar to that of Milnor-Moore?

Comment: (Recall that the bar construction gives proper projective resolutions. This gives a spectral sequence of a double complex, as you state. See page 243, Proposition 7.3 in McCleary's *A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences*.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ok, thank you